# How to use AutoCompleteFilter mapbox?

Tags: android, autocomplete, mapbox

I am using mapbox for working with map in my application.
 For search places

I have added AutocompleteView and AutoCompeteAdapter to my project like below:

```
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapterMap extends AutocompleteAdapter  {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocompleteAdapter";
    private CharacterStyle styleBold = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    private Context context;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    /**
    * Current results returned by this adapter.
    */


    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapterMap(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_autocomplete_list, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvPlaceName = (CustomFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlaceName);
            holder.tvPlaceAddress = (CustomFontTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPlaceAddress);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        CarmenFeature item = getItem(position);
        holder.tvPlaceName.setText(item.text());
        holder.tvPlaceAddress.setText(item.placeName());
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        CustomFontTextView tvPlaceName, tvPlaceAddress;

    }

}
```

Now I want filter result for specific country  using  AutoCompleteFilter by mapbox. How to do it?

Comment: You need to set `.setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)`
                        `.setCountry("Your Country Name")` for _ AutoCompleteFilter_

Comment: This com.mapbox.android.search.autocomplete.AutoCompleteFilter is of mapbox not of com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutoCompleteFilter ,
.setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY) .setCountry("Your Country Name") will not working with it

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/plugins/overview/places/). Might be help you